# Куда теряются данные из массива?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

В приложении реализована функция обращения к скрипту на сервере для получения отзывов пользователей.

Забираю так (заполняю массив *feedbacksArray* экземплярами класса *Feedback*):

```
NSString * URL = @"http://supersite.ru/script.php";
NSURL * nsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationFeedback = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operationFeedback.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operationFeedback setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSONResponse){

    feedbacksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [JSONResponse count]; i++)
    {
        _zeroCountFeedbacks = [[JSONResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"_id"];
        _feedName = [[JSONResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"username"];
        _feedDate = [[JSONResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];
        _feedText = [[JSONResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"feedback"];
        _feedGood = [[JSONResponse objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"vote"];

        // Если отзывы есть, то заполняем массив отзывов
        if (![_zeroCountFeedbacks isEqualToString:@"null"])
        {
            [feedbacksArray addObject:[[Feedback alloc]initWithName:_feedName andDate:_feedDate andFeedback:_feedText andRating:_feedGood]];
        }
    }
[self.tabFiveFeedbacks reloadData];    
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err)
{

}];
[operationFeedback start];
```

При помощи маркера проверяю - массив заполнен корректно (число элементов и заполнение полей верное).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я пытаюсь заполнить этими данными UITableView. И тут начинается самое интересное:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedbackCell";
    FeedbackCell * cellFeedback = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Feedback * feedbackObject;
    feedbackObject = [feedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cellFeedback.feedNameLabel.text = feedbackObject.name;
    cellFeedback.feedDateLabel.text = feedbackObject.date;
    cellFeedback.feedTextLabel.text = feedbackObject.feedback;

    if ([feedbackObject.isGood isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        cellFeedback.feedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_ratingup_green.png"];
    }
    if ([feedbackObject.isGood isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cellFeedback.feedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_ratingdown_red.png"];
    }
    return cellFeedback;

}
```

В результате: получаю корректное значение в `numberofrowsinsection:` (массив отзывов имеет длину, скажем, 3), но при этом в нем все поля становятся `nil` (значения которых не равны):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом могли обнулиться данные??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Feedback` поля были `(weak, nonatomic)`. Исправил на `(strong, nonatomic)` и все заработало.